# Applying counter on log

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr

**Code:**

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set "dt=%%a"

set "YY=%dt:~2,2%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"

set "today=%YY%%MM%%DD%"

findstr /i /c:"The_database_has_been_locked." "C:\admin\logs\*%today%.log" >> "C:\records\Error.txt"
```

**Problem Description:**

I have some log files under path C:\admin\logs\ which are being created everyday having date of that day in their names.

I want to search a specific error message in all the files created today only And as soon as error message found, immediately append the complete line having error message into a text file named Error.txt.

**I've scheduled this script to run everyday on every 10 mins.**

The problem I am facing here is, Its appending specified error message occured on a particular time instance multiple times . I mean on every run its appending previously parsed error messages too, which I don't want.

I want to appened the error message only one time into Error.txt for a particular time instance of error-occurence on current date.

Could you please help me out here ?

**EDIT:Log snippet**

Log snippet:

```
2013-12-06 16:29:31 10.35.44.195 GET /perform/all/per_cubes.asp - 80 - 172.23.45.72 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/4.0;+NGD_build;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+InfoPath.3;+MS-RTC+LM+8) 200 0 0 328
2013-12-06 16:29:33 10.35.44.195 GET /perform/all/per_cubes.asp |62|80004005|[Microsoft][ODBC_Microsoft_Access_Driver]_The_database_has_been_locked. 80 - 62.239.225.222 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/5.0;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+SLCC2) 500 0 0 468
2013-12-06 16:29:44 10.35.44.195 GET /perform/all/per_cubes.asp |62|80004005|Unspecified_error 80 - 10.225.206.76 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/4.0;+NGD_build;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+InfoPath.3;+MS-RTC+LM+8) 500 0 0 93
```

Appending error message to Error.txt like below (only once for a specific time on current date):

```
2013-12-06 16:29:33 10.35.44.195 GET /perform/all/per_cubes.asp |62|80004005|[Microsoft][ODBC_Microsoft_Access_Driver]_The_database_has_been_locked. 80 - 62.239.225.222 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/5.0;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+SLCC2) 500 0 0 468
```

Comment: So you're running this script multiple times in one day, and therefore it is getting duplicate entries in `Error.txt`?

Comment: Can you give a representative snippet of one of your logfile and. And describe the output you need.

Comment: @unclemeat..yes, you're right ! I've scheduled this script to run everyday on every 10 mins.

Comment: @sachadee..I've uploaded the log snippet and required output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=c:\destdir"

:: Need to put YOUR setting of %TODAY% in here - I'm using constants for testing

SET today=20140109

FOR %%a IN ("%sourcedir%"\beenprocessed*.txt) DO IF /i NOT "%%a"=="%sourcedir%\beenprocessed%today%.txt" DEL "%%a"
IF NOT EXIST "%sourcedir%\*%today%.log" GOTO :eof

ECHO dummy>>"%sourcedir%\beenprocessed%today%.txt"
findstr /i /c:"The_database_has_been_locked." "%sourcedir%\*%today%.log" >"%sourcedir%\beINGprocessednow.txt"
FINDSTR /i /v /b /e /g:"%sourcedir%\beenprocessed%today%.txt" "%sourcedir%\beINGprocessednow.txt" >>"%destdir%\Error.txt"
type "%sourcedir%\beINGprocessednow.txt" >> "%sourcedir%\beenprocessed%today%.txt" 
GOTO :EOF
```

You'd need to insert your setting of `%today%` - I just used a constant. Also, I've set source and destination directories as variables. Just a matter of making changes.

I'm not fussed whether the `...beenprocessed...` and `...beingprocessednow...` files are in `%sourcedir%`, `%destdir%`, `%temp%` or `%someotherdir%`. Up to the programmer to choose.

The principle is this:

append a dummy string into `beenprocessed...`. This either creates a file or appends to it, a string that simply won't be of interest (it fails the '...database_has_been...` filter).

Find all of the target records in the logs and place them in a file `beingprocessednow`.

Find all of the lines in `beingprocessednow` that don't appear in `beenprocessed` - ie. the new lines, and append them to the `error.txt` file.

Append the entire contents of `beingprocessednow` to `beenprocessed` which includes the new data

At startup, the `beenprocessed` files for any day other than today are deleted.

`dummy` needs to be added to the "words to exclude" because `findstr ../g` requires at least one string in the file. `dummy` can't be a valid word which occupies exectly one line (`/b /e`) because all lines of interest contain the target string.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the log entries are all unique in some way.

```
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
set searchString=The_database_has_been_locked.
set sourceFile=C:\admin\logs\*%today%.log

for /f "delims=~!" %%a in ('findstr /i /c:"%searchString%" "%sourceFile%"') do (
    set skip=0
    for /f "delims=~!" %%b in ('findstr /i /c:"%%a" "Error.txt"') do set skip=1
    if !skip!==0 echo %%a & echo %%a >> Error.txt
)
```

The internal for loop will only be able to set the variable `skip` if it finds `%%a` in `Error.txt`. Therefore, if skip is not defined then there will not be a duplicate entry, and you can append the error to `Error.txt`.

Comment: @unclement...Its working only when new entries are being added in actual log file at the top, but as we know that will never be case because a new entry is always being added at last (never at top) by default. Could you please modify it for that way working ?